# how to restart apache in zend server

Tags: apache, zend-framework, zend-server

I have Zend Server CE installed on my windows computer. I have made some changes in httpd cofig file.  Now I want to restart apache.  I haven't found any option to restart apache. There is just one option "Restart PHP".

Can any body tell me from where I can restart apache in Zend Server CE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say you are using windows?

Zend Server with Apache installs a small application that lives in your tray called **"*Apache Monitor*"** you can use this application to restart apache.

Comment: good... This is what I was looking for. +1 for this. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 15):

first you need to check the "Zend server" installation location.

Say for example.

If you installed zend server @ /usr/local/zend/

Use the below command to restart the Zend Server.

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
net stop Apache2.2-Zend && net start Apache2.2-Zend
```

Comment: did..didn't solve the issue. Command gave an error of not exist :-(

Comment: Open up services.msc and look for a service with a name that contains "Apache". If you can find it, use that name instead of "Apache2.2-Zend", and that should fix your problem. Hopefully!

Comment: Name is same... even then problem is there :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, apache should show up as a service.

Use the Windows search function to find the services window.

Select Apache. Stop and start the service and all your config files etc should have updated.