# How can I restart Apache in Zend Server CE?

Tags: apache, zend-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to restart apache in zend server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374424/how-to-restart-apache-in-zend-server)

I installed Zend Server in Windows 7. I made a few changes in the http-vhost file. 
How can I restart the Apache in Zend Server CE?

Comment: Please see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374424/how-to-restart-apache-in-zend-server?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could restart Apache via Apache Monitor.